# Google Analytics Issue for Magento to PayPal

Tags: magento, paypal

So, having discovered that customers are not returning to our website after making their PayPal payments, our Google Analytics reports are wonky as the landing page (success.phtml) which generates the order completion history/goal is never achieved.

Is there a PayPal APi callback to Magento which can generate the correct Google Analytics data? Is there a way to generate GA code at the PayPal end?

Any pointers appreciated!

Thanks, Joe.

Answer (score 1):

a better question for you is why are your customers not reaching the `success.phtml`?

Go to Website Payments under Profile on the PayPal website. Setup your return URL and enter the succes url there...

If your customers don't return because they close their browser before returning to the shop:

You could remove the script from success.phtml and add a serverside-call to GA using something like [serversidegoogleanalytics](http://code.google.com/p/serversidegoogleanalytics) but you'll have to implement this for all paymentmethods you are accepting... This serversidecall would be done in the success-action within the controller of the paypal module

Comment: We managed to ask a couple of customers why they didn't return to the website after making a payment and they basically said that they knew the order was completed by paying, so why bother waiting for PayPal tp process the redirection back to our website.

Everyone's in a hurry, so why wait a couple of seconds to be redirected back to the website!

Redirection is set back to our website with PP's profile.

Comment: Than I dont think you can help it... Paypal is not going to let you execute javascript on their pages...

Comment: I'm hoping someone will be able to detail an APi callback to our Magento website that can process the same data?

Comment: Well... you could remove the script from success.phtml and add a serverside-call to GA using something like https://code.google.com/p/serversidegoogleanalytics/ but you'll have to implement this for all paymentmethods you are accepting... This serversidecall would be done in the success-action within the controller of the paypal module

Comment: Interesting ... I'll have a look at that, thanks! :o]